# Unable to install Python packages using pip on Azure LAMP shell server

Tags: python-2.7, azure, ssh

I've tried installing Python packages using pip on my Azure Lamp SSH server, but am unable to do so from the shell. I'm running Python 2.7

For pendulum, the error message says:

```
Collecting Pendulum
  Using cached pendulum-1.4.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0.0,>=2.6.0.0 in /usr/local/l                                                                             ib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Pendulum)
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal<2.0.0.0,>=1.5.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/pytho                                                                             n2.7/dist-packages (from Pendulum)
Requirement already satisfied: pytzdata>=2018.3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/                                                                             dist-packages (from Pendulum)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package                                                                             s (from python-dateutil<3.0.0.0,>=2.6.0.0->Pendulum)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (f                                                                             rom tzlocal<2.0.0.0,>=1.5.0.0->Pendulum)
Building wheels for collected packages: Pendulum
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Pendulum ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokeniz                                                                             e;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7TNfPO/Pendulum/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',                                                                              open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code                                                                             , __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmprJOXPqpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution op                                                                             tion: 'python_requires'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/interval.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/_global.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/translator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/pendulum.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/helpers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/date.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/period.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  copying pendulum/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/_extensions
  copying pendulum/_extensions/helpers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum                                                                             /_extensions
  copying pendulum/_extensions/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulu                                                                             m/_extensions
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/formatting
  copying pendulum/formatting/formatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulu                                                                             m/formatting
  copying pendulum/formatting/classic_formatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7                                                                             /pendulum/formatting
  copying pendulum/formatting/alternative_formatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64                                                                             -2.7/pendulum/formatting
  copying pendulum/formatting/difference_formatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-                                                                             2.7/pendulum/formatting
  copying pendulum/formatting/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum                                                                             /formatting
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/ro.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/ko.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/lv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/ja.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/lt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/th.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/et.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/hy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/fr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/fa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/da.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/fo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/sv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/bg.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/uz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/sr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/fi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/tr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/zh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/id.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/ru.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/ca.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/sl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/pl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/az.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/bn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/sk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/nl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/ar.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/he.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/es.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/mk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/en.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/de.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/ms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/vi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/el.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/uk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/hu.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/hr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/sq.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/cs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/zh_tw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/ka.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/it.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/nn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/pt_br.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/eu.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/af.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/eo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  copying pendulum/lang/gl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/mixins
  copying pendulum/mixins/default.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/mixi                                                                             ns
  copying pendulum/mixins/interval.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/mix                                                                             ins
  copying pendulum/mixins/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/mix                                                                             ins
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/parsing
  copying pendulum/parsing/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/pa                                                                             rsing
  copying pendulum/parsing/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/pars                                                                             ing
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/parsing/exceptions
  copying pendulum/parsing/exceptions/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/                                                                             pendulum/parsing/exceptions
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
  copying pendulum/tz/loader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
  copying pendulum/tz/transition.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
  copying pendulum/tz/local_timezone.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/t                                                                             z
  copying pendulum/tz/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
  copying pendulum/tz/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
  copying pendulum/tz/transition_type.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/                                                                             tz
  copying pendulum/tz/timezone.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
  copying pendulum/tz/timezone_info.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
  error: can't copy 'pendulum/mixins': doesn't exist or not a regular file

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for Pendulum
  Running setup.py clean for Pendulum
Failed to build Pendulum
Installing collected packages: Pendulum
  Running setup.py install for Pendulum ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, token                                                                             ize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7TNfPO/Pendulum/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open                                                                             ', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(co                                                                             de, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Mc4aH7-record/install-record.t                                                                             xt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution                                                                              option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/interval.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/_global.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/translator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/pendulum.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/helpers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/date.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/period.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    copying pendulum/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/_extensions
    copying pendulum/_extensions/helpers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendul                                                                             um/_extensions
    copying pendulum/_extensions/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendu                                                                             lum/_extensions
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/formatting
    copying pendulum/formatting/formatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendu                                                                             lum/formatting
    copying pendulum/formatting/classic_formatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2                                                                             .7/pendulum/formatting
    copying pendulum/formatting/alternative_formatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_                                                                             64-2.7/pendulum/formatting
    copying pendulum/formatting/difference_formatter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_6                                                                             4-2.7/pendulum/formatting
    copying pendulum/formatting/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendul                                                                             um/formatting
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/ro.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/ko.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/lv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/ja.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/lt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/th.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/et.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/hy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/fr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/fa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/da.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/fo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/sv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/bg.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/uz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/sr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/fi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/tr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/zh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/id.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/ru.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/ca.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/sl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/pl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/az.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/bn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/sk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/nl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/ar.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/he.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/es.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/mk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/en.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/de.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/ms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/vi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/el.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/uk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/hu.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lan                                                                             g
    copying pendulum/lang/hr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/sq.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/cs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/zh_tw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/ka.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/it.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/nn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/pt_br.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/eu.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/af.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/eo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    copying pendulum/lang/gl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/lang
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/mixins
    copying pendulum/mixins/default.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/mi                                                                             xins
    copying pendulum/mixins/interval.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/m                                                                             ixins
    copying pendulum/mixins/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/m                                                                             ixins
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/parsing
    copying pendulum/parsing/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/                                                                             parsing
    copying pendulum/parsing/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/pa                                                                             rsing
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/parsing/exceptions
    copying pendulum/parsing/exceptions/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.                                                                             7/pendulum/parsing/exceptions
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
    copying pendulum/tz/loader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
    copying pendulum/tz/transition.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
    copying pendulum/tz/local_timezone.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum                                                                             /tz
    copying pendulum/tz/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
    copying pendulum/tz/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
    copying pendulum/tz/transition_type.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulu                                                                             m/tz
    copying pendulum/tz/timezone.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/tz
    copying pendulum/tz/timezone_info.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pendulum/                                                                             tz
    error: can't copy 'pendulum/mixins': doesn't exist or not a regular file

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-b                                                                             uild-7TNfPO/Pendulum/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=                                                                             f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"                                                                              install --record /tmp/pip-Mc4aH7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-exte                                                                             rnally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7TNfPO/Pend                                                                             ulum/
```

It looks like it goes halfway through the process but then breaks down somewhere in the middle. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating setuptools, it's probably an [old issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/483) causing this :

```
pip install -U setuptools
```